# How to make a functional Materialize Search Bar

Tags: javascript, materialize

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper green lighten-2">
        <form>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input id="search" type="search" required>
                <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hello, I have the above materialize html from the website that initializes the visual component of a searchbar, but as of now it is not very functional. How do I make is so that when I type and search, it redirects me to a specific HTML page?

Comment: Some server-side code is missing

Comment: @Nerdvoso is there no way to do this using plain old Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular or React or PHP to make it dynamic, 
Using only a HTML you canot make it dynamic.